# can not access the public methods from fragment object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I saved the fragment object using [Streets Of Boston's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager)

And pulled out a fragment

```
 Fragment fragment = myPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragments(nowPosition);
 if (fragment == null)
 {
     return; 
 }
```

but i'm can not access the public methods from fragment object
fragment .

this method is in a fragment

```
 public void dowork()
 {
     //WORK!
 }

 public static void dowork2()
 {
     //WORK!
 }
```

fragment.dowork(); -> dowork is not found
fragment.dowork2(); -> dowork2 is not found

How can access?
thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to call these methods on the fragment as instantiated in your example, you'll need to cast the fragment to your class. So if your fragment is of class `MyFragment` you need to do

```
 MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) myPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragments(nowPosition);
```

Then you will be able to call the methods you declared in your fragment class.

Also, static methods should be called on the class, not an instance, so it would be correct to do

```
 MyFragment.dowork2();
```

if that method actually is static.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast that Fragment to your Subclass of Fragment.
The reason you cannot access those methods is because they are not available in fragment.They are in your implementation of the Fragment class.